# Visualize a generic GeoJson file with Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I want to plot some polygons contained in a GeoJson file. Is it possible to visualize a GeoJson file in Plotly that is not linked directly to a real world location?

As example I can use GeoPandas to plot a generic GeoJson file:

```python
import json
geodata = json.loads(
"""{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]]]},
        "properties": {"id": "upper_left"}
      },
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0,0],[1,1],[1,0]]]},
        "properties": {"id": "lower_right"}
      }
    ]
}""")

import geopandas as gpd
df_shapes = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geodata["features"])
df_shapes.plot(color="none")
```

The result displays the two polygons (triangles) contained in the GeoJson:

[image: two polygons]

How would I plot the same map using Plotly? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38601132/2129801) suggests to use scope to limit the base map that is shown. What can be done if there is no base map?

(I am not asking how to plot a square with a line. The GeoJson is just a simplified example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[plotly shapes](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/) can be drawn.

### using traces

It's then a case of **list** / **dict** comprehensions to restructure **geojson** polygons to **plotly** structure

```
import json

geodata = json.loads(
    """{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]]]},
        "properties": {"id": "upper_left"}
      },
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0,0],[1,1],[1,0]]]},
        "properties": {"id": "lower_right"}
      }
    ]
}"""
)

go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            **{
                "x": [p[0] for p in f["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]],
                "y": [p[1] for p in f["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]],
                "fill": "toself",
                "name": f["properties"]["id"],
            }
        )
        for f in geodata["features"]
    ]
).update_layout(height=200, width=200, showlegend=False, margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"b":0})
```

[image]

### using `shapes`

- use **geopandas** geometry to get SVG then extract *path*
- add theses polygons as shapes onto **layout**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# input to plotly is path.  use shapely geometry svg path for this
df_shapes = df_shapes.assign(
    svgpath=df_shapes["geometry"].apply(
        lambda p: BeautifulSoup(p.svg()).find("path")["d"]
    )
)

go.Figure(
    layout=dict(
        height=200,
        width=200,
        showlegend=False,
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        xaxis={"range": [0, 1]},
        yaxis={"range": [0, 1]},
        shapes=[{"type": "path", "path": p} for p in df_shapes["svgpath"]],
    )
)
```