# Plotting a geopandas dataframe geometry with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, geopandas

In this [notebook](https://github.com/jddorellanao/fisicarocas/blob/main/seismic%20surveys_beta.ipynb) I plot the geometry of a seismic survey design (first figure), I want to make it interactive with plotly but I've failed.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67765376/visualize-a-generic-geojson-file-with-plotly) and tried the solution. First converting my geodataframe to GeoJson, It looks like this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
    {"id": "0", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"SID": 0, "station": "r"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [574950.0, 4710050.0]}},
    {"id": "1", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"SID": 1, "station": "r"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [575050.0, 4710050.0]}},
}
```

And then plot it

```
go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            **{
                "x": [p[0] for p in f["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]],
                "y": [p[1] for p in f["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]],
                "fill": "toself",
                "name": f["properties"]["id"],
            }
        )
        for f in geodata["features"]
    ]
).update_layout(height=200, width=200, showlegend=False, margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"b":0})
```

I got the next error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

How can my problem be solved?

Comment: are you just trying to scatter points?  the answer you referenced is where geojson defines polygons not points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is far simpler given it's just points.

### straight scatter

```
import plotly.express as px

px.scatter(survey, x=survey.geometry.x, y=survey.geometry.y, color="station")
```

[image]

### scatter with map layer as well

- need to consider CRS projection

```
survey_ = survey.to_crs("epsg:4386")
px.scatter_mapbox(
    survey_, lat=survey_.geometry.y, lon=survey_.geometry.x, color="station"
).update_layout(mapbox={"style": "carto-positron", "zoom": 12})
```

[image]